# Proxy Server: Windows 2k8, SSL

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, proxy, arr

I have a client with a server sitting in a remote location dual-homed into two subnets. Hosts in Subnet A has no internet access, those in subnet B do. Hosts in subnet A need to access a website using SSL but only have access to said server.

Looking for a proxy solution which will run on Server 2k8, not interfere with IIS running on the same host, and will proxy client requests from subnet A through subnet B to the internet.

The situation is fairly absurd and the client does not want to:

Configure any routing based solution
Install any network hardware
Use ISA server
Install any Linux hosts (for squid)

I've looked primarily at trying get this to work using IIS7's ARR module. But some advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a maintained Windows port of [Squid](http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/).

You can get pretty fancy with Squid, as far as ACLs go.  I'd give that a try first.